# Lazy loading large data

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

I am fetching data from various resources through ajax and displaying them on page, jQuery.ready() . And  applying **isotope** on `$(window).load(function(){});`.

Since writing from these number of resources takes time, it takes time to apply isotope masonry view. It is noticeable from HTML page. So for an alternate, I fetched 4-5 resources on jQuery.ready() => set isotope on `$(window).load(function(){});` => then fetched data from rest resources on jQuery.load().

But any call in load() is not happening.

What should I do for this lazy loading, or rather lazy calling?

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function(){})` executes its callback when the window (and everything it contains, including images) has loaded. However, it does not take account of ajax requests that are made later. Therefore, I suspect your callback is firing (put in a `console.log('callback called')` line to check) but it is happening before JQuery has returned the results of your ajax requests and so does not work as you expect.

I've never used isotope, but I suspect the answer to your problem is to add some code to the success method in your ajax calls. This page of the isotope docs is probably what you need: `http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html`